# Zip file download with folder structure and multiple files with same name in php

Tags: php, fpdf, zip, php-ziparchive

When I try to download zip file it comes with folder path and file with same name.

```
$files = array('Estimate.pdf','Requisition.pdf');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
$zip->addFile($path.'/'.$file,$file);
}
$zip->close();
```